# Silverlight streaming video

Tags: silverlight, video, encoding, streaming

I'm creating a web platform destined to the customers of a certain company. The company requires that the platform allows the streaming of videos.

It's important to note that the company will be the one to add the videos to the platform, dinamically, from a software built by me for that purpose, and each video will be referenced on a sql server table.

I've never done streaming before so I'm asking 2 things:

The first is about some guidance in silverlight streaming(tutorials, articles, examples, etc)

The other is my main concern. I have a few video samples from the company, and all of them are over 200 MBytes and can go up to 2GB, so I know I have to re-encode them to become smaller. But, how do I do this... I mean, do I have to re-enconde them, manually, one at a time, or is there a way to do it automatically as a new video is added?

I have Expression Studio Encoder 4 pro, but never really used it, and as far as I can tell, I have to manually add each video to do the enconding. Again... is there a way to do this dinamically??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all video formats and encodings are supported by Silverlight. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx) for a list of supported formats. You will probably need to recompress your videos not only to reduce their size but also to normalize the format.

The recompression could be done in a windows service running in the background, the more appropriated libraries to be used will probably depend on the target format you will use. For wmv files I would recommend using Windows Media Format SDK,the (currently deprecated) Windows Media Encoder SDK or its succesor Expression Studio Encoder SDK. For using H264 as target I would recommend using [ffmepg](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Encoding).

You should decide on a delivery protocol depending on the number of users you can forsee for your website. HTTP might not be the best choice, since there are other protocols like [RTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol), usually more suitable for video streaming.